# How to migrate a UWP app's authentication from OneDrive SDK to Graph

Tags: authentication, uwp, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

So I have this really old UWP app that has been using the Live/OneDrive SDK to provide authentication and identification for at least 7 years now.  The app is registered with Microsoft Account Authentication which provides a Client Id and Client Secret to identify the app when an authentication request is made.

When I use the SDK for authentication (OnlineIdAuthenticationProvider), it returns a unique Id (CurrentAccountSession.UserId) with which I can determine which of my users is using the app and then use that unique Id to persist/retrieve information the user provides.

The problem is....The OneDrive SDK is super old (hasn't been touched in over 3 years), outdated (.NET 4.51...no .NetStandard implementation) and Microsoft is pushing everyone to use MSAL and Graph instead.  Fine.

**But how can I do that and still be able to tie the person who is logged in to the app to the information I am storing for her/him?**

From what I'm seeing, in order to use the new SDKs, I have to register my app, again, in the Azure portal and use a new Application (client) ID.  If so, when my user logs in...my expectation is that any identifier that's returned to my app in the authentication process will not be the same as the UserId I've been using for almost a decade.

Has anyone done this?  I can't be the only person who has encountered this problem...can I?
Any help would be greatly appreciated....